Why are white lines appearing as an overlay on some fonts?
In my browser some fonts with particularly notched shapes are displayed incorrectly in some sizes for me. I'm thinking that this is related to edge-detection, but I'm not sure what are the steps to fixing this issue.
I'm using Chrome 109.0.5414.168; I rarely get other random font issues (so it's probably not just the Chrome), but I've never captured any screenshots of these temporary glitches.
Here is an extreme example (Yarndings 20) to illustrate the problem clearly
Normal:



Error:




I bet it is just a rounding error that makes the lines appear, and that means its a problem with the font.

examine the font with a font editor

Yeah, @LPChip, that's something like what I've thought. The question is how to fix that and why did it start doing this at some point. (Thx for the edits, btw, I hadn't been getting much sleep lately)

This might be affected by the text-rendering CSS property.
